# Flipped Einsteins in the Einstein Tiling

Tags: mathematics, knowledge, geometry, tiling

The [single-tile aperiodic tiling](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecsk/hat) by Goodman-Strauss, Kaplan, Myers and Smith has been all the rage recently:

[image]

In this tiling a minority of tiles, coloured purple above, are flipped with respect to the rest of the tiling; the flipped tiles form a rough hexagonal lattice (indeed an infinitely distorted lattice as the *word* aperiodic dictates). As such the ratio of flipped tiles to total tiles in a finite patch of the tiling converges to a positive constant $p<\frac12$ as the patch expands to fill the entire plane. What is the exact value of $p$?

(I know the answer to this question.)

Comment: I love this tiling. It is so amazing that such a simple tile aligned to a regular grid will only produce aperiodic tiling patterns. When I read the paper it was a bit of a surprise to be mentioned in the acknowledgements, as I had no direct involvement at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your choice of partial tiling (and description)  suggests we should be dealing with

> this substitution scheme, from the paper: (note the similarity between the provided image and the twice-inflated $H_7$)
>  [image]
>  Letting $x, y$ denote the asymptotic frequencies of $H_7, H_8$, we obtain $x = \frac{x+y}{6x+7y}, y = \frac{5x+6y}{6x+7y}$.
>  Since $x+y=1$, we get $x=\frac{1}{7-x}$, so $x^2-7x+1=0$ and $x = \frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Similarly, $y = \frac{5+y}{6+y}$, so $y^2+5y-5 = 0$ and $y = \frac{3\sqrt{5}-5}{2}$.  (We could have subtracted from 1, but I include this as a sanity check.)
>  Anyway, the asymptotic density of reflected tiles is $\frac{x+y}{7x+8y} = \frac{1}{7+y} = \frac{2}{9+3\sqrt{5}} = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{6}$, which is roughly **12.73%**.

Answer (score 5):

[AxiomaticSystem's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/120242) reproduces a diagram from [Smith et al] showing a substitution system. We may start with a single tile, which is 1 right-way-up tile and 0 flipped tiles, and substitute a patch the author calls $H_8$, which consists of 7 right-way-up tiles and 1 flipped tile. This diagram shows an $H_8$, and then shows how the $H_8$ may in turn be replaced by a patch containing 48 right-way-up tiles and 7 flipped tiles, which may in turn be replaced by a patch containing 329 right-way-up tiles and 48 flipped tiles. These numbers $a_i=0, 1, 7, 48, 329, \dots$ ([OEIS A004187](https://oeis.org/A004187)) obey the recurrence $a_i=7a_{i-1}-a_{i-2}$. The ratio limit $\lim_{i\to\infty} (a_i/a_{i-1})=(7+3\sqrt5)/2$ (the reciprocal of the constant given by AxiomaticSystem). This is also $\phi^4$; Smith et al credit Adam Goucher with noticing that. We also have $a_i=F(4i)/3$ where $F(j)$ means the $j$th Fibonacci number.

Comment: Thanks for the details! The post by Adam Goucher is [Aperiodic monotile | Complex Projective 4-Space](https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2023/03/21/aperiodic-monotile/)

Comment: What is the ratio of flipped tiles for the other infinite tilings? And how many unique infinite tilings are there - 4? (H == T, P, F, and H7==H8?)